# Pagination does not work after changing queryset in get_context_data

Tags: python, django

Pagination works ok until I add `reverse` arg to QS for ordering queryset in reverse mode. After it pagination is broke.
I can use `get()` function and paginate it there, but I think that for this issue should be better solution. Thanks

model.py:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    comment = models.CharField()
    date_add = models.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_add']
```

view.py:

```
class LogView(ListView):
    model = UserLog
    template_name = 'log.html'
    context_object_name = 'log_list'
    paginate_by = 13

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Log.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).all()

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(LogView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if 'reverse' in self.request.GET:
            context['log_list'] = Log.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).all().order_by('date_add')
        return context
```

Comment: That's correct, since the pagination is done in the `super(...).get_context_data()`, by overriding it, you thus "bypass" the pagination.

Comment: I don't see a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the code that runs the queryset to `get_queryset`, so that it runs before the queryset is paginated.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Log.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).all()
    if 'reverse' in self.request.GET:
        queryset = queryset.order_by('date_add')
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 1):

The pagination is called in the [**`get_context_data`** of the **`MultipleObjectMixin`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.1.x/django/views/generic/list.py#L113):

> ```
> def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
>     """Get the context for this view."""
>     queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list
>     page_size = self.get_paginate_by(queryset)
>     context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(queryset)
>     if page_size:
>         paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
>         context = {
>             'paginator': paginator,
>             'page_obj': page,
>             'is_paginated': is_paginated,
>             'object_list': queryset
>         }
>     else:
>         context = {
>             'paginator': None,
>             'page_obj': None,
>             'is_paginated': False,
>             'object_list': queryset
>         }
>     if context_object_name is not None:
>         context[context_object_name] = queryset
>     context.update(kwargs)
>     return super().get_context_data(**context)
> ```

By overriding the element of the dictionary, you thus *bypass* this pagination.

I think it is however better in this use-case to transfer the logic to the `get_queryset` method, in that case, you even do *not* have to override the `get_context_data`:

```
class LogView(ListView):
    model = UserLog
    template_name = 'log.html'
    context_object_name = 'log_list'
    paginate_by = 13

    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'reverse' in self.request.GET:
            return Log.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).all().order_by('date_add')
        else:
            return Log.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).all()
```

Note that the above has two potential problems:

1. you do not order the queryset in case `'reverse'` is *not* in `self.request.GET`, which means that - unless you order in the model - there is no order, and hence pagination might go wrong over multiple pages;
2. since pagiantion uses already a `page` key in `request.GET`, this can result in some trouble in the links that change the GET parameter, since if you specify an url with `?page=3`, the `reverse` key will get dropped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right about 2. But it's another thing that I should solve